# MySQL Workbench installation program failing to detect Python

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to get a new MySQL Workbench install to work, but every time I try I get this error:

```
Connector/Python (3.4) 2.1.3 Python 3.4 Not Installed
```

I had Python already installed on this computer, but I dutifully when back and updated to the latest version (3.5.2) but I'm still getting the same error.

Any idea what's up?

Comment: This is very likely a python installation problem, so I'd ask about that specifically. MySQL Workbench and the Conn/P only use what they find.

Comment: @MikeLischke Python is working fine, though.